# AWS S3 list all objects by object created/modified date descending order NodeJs

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm using NodeJs to list of objects in a S3 bucket by created/modified object date descending order but not finding any option to pass descending order option

```
// Load the AWS SDK for Node.js
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
// Set the region 
AWS.config.update({region: 'REGION'});

// Create S3 service object
s3 = new AWS.S3({apiVersion: '2006-03-01'});

// Create the parameters for calling listObjects
var bucketParams = {
 Bucket : 'BUCKET_NAME',
};

// Call S3 to obtain a list of the objects in the bucket
s3.listObjects(bucketParams, function(err, data) {
  if (err) {
    console.log("Error", err);
  } else {
    console.log("Success", data);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 6):

Per [Amazon docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/v2-RESTBucketGET.html) the list will return the objects in UTF-8 character encoding in lexicographical order and there's no way to ask for the results to return in a different sorting.

You'll have to sort the results by yourself:

```
s3.listObjects(bucketParams, function(err, data) {
  if (err) {
    console.log("Error", err);
  } else {
    console.log("Success", JSON.stringify(data.Contents.sort(o => o.Key)); // example
  }
});
```

**UPDATE**

[listObjectsV2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_ListObjectsV2.html) is the recommended approach, from [the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#listObjectsV2-property):

```
const params = {
  Bucket: 'STRING_VALUE', /* required */
  ContinuationToken: 'STRING_VALUE',
  Delimiter: 'STRING_VALUE',
  EncodingType: url,
  ExpectedBucketOwner: 'STRING_VALUE',
  FetchOwner: true || false,
  MaxKeys: 'NUMBER_VALUE',
  Prefix: 'STRING_VALUE',
  RequestPayer: requester,
  StartAfter: 'STRING_VALUE'
};
s3.listObjectsV2(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```

Comment: Is it UTF-8 character encoding of the key name ?

Comment: @Tany of the entire response' body

Comment: Good luck with this solution if you have millions of objects in the bucket :)

Comment: @Selindek you're right, I suspect that now [listObjectsV2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#listObjectsV2-property) is the recommended approach, I'll update the answer

Comment: Maybe I'm missing it, but where exactly does your update show the sort order?  Or does your update still require pulling the entire contents of the bucket and then sorting 'locally'?

Comment: @lowcrawler the update refers to the newer api (V2). AFAIK the sorting limitation still exists as was stated in the first part of the answer